# Migrate link field from xml

Tags: migrations

My XML looks like this:

```xml
    <dynamic-element name="link-extern" >
      <dynamic-element name="link-extern-text" type="text">
         <dynamic-content><![CDATA[Myfirst title]]></dynamic-content>
      </dynamic-element>
      <dynamic-element name="url-extern" type="text" >
         <dynamic-content><![CDATA[http://www.myurl.com]]></dynamic-content>
      </dynamic-element>
      <dynamic-element name="new-window" type="boolean">
         <dynamic-content><![CDATA[false]]></dynamic-content>
      </dynamic-element>
    </dynamic-element>
```

I have a Drupal 8 link field. 
The **source** looks like:

```
   -
     name: link_extern_text
     label: 'Link extern text'
     selector: 'article_content/*[@name="link-extern"]/*[@name="link-extern-text"]/*'
   -
     name: link_extern_url
     label: 'Link extern url'
     selector: 'article_content/*[@name="link-extern"]/*[@name="url-extern"]/*'
   -
     name: link_extern_target
     label: 'Target of external url'
     selector: 'article_content/*[@name="link-extern"]/*[@name="new-window"]/*'
```

My YML **process** configuration looks like:

```
'field_link_extern/uri': link_extern_url
'field_link_extern/title': link_extern_text
'field_link_extern/options/attributes/target':
  plugin: static_map
    source: link_extern_target
    map:
      'false': '_self'
      'true': '_blank'
    default_value: '_blank'
    ignore_case: true
```

These settings work in the case when there is only one link-extern element. On multiple links it breaks. Perhaps using the sub_process plugin could be done, but i have no idea how. Can someone point me in the direction?

Comment: You should give us your whole yml config.

Comment: It's a bit long for the whole yml file to fit in. All the information is there.
I have also tried this approach, but failed.
`
   tmp_field_link_external:
    plugin: get
    source:
      - link_extern_url
      - link_extern_text

  'field_link':
    plugin: sub_process
    source: '@tmp_field_link_external'
    process:
      uri: "0"
      title: "1"
`

Comment: Then give at least the whole source part

Comment: Are you refering to this:

```
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: file
  urls: 'modules/custom/article_importer/migrations/news_article4.xml'
  data_parser_plugin: simple_xml
  item_selector: /SELECT/DATA_RECORD
```

Comment: how about extending your item_selector with article_content/*[@name="link-extern"] and change the source selector to fit this too.

Comment: There is data that is outside the scope of article_content/*[@name="link-extern"]  which i need.